# How do I highlight entire row instead of it's text-input border?

Tags: jquery

```js
function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);

  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    validateNresult();
  })


  $('.allrb').change(valueE);


});


function validateNresult() 
{
    var anyFieldIsEmpty = $(".numFr").filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value).length === 0 ;
        }).css("border","1px solid red");
    var anyFieldIsEmpty1 = $(".numIr").filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value).length === 0 ;
        }).css("border","1px solid red");


}
```

```css
    input[type=number]
    {
      width:25px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir3" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr3" class="numFr" id="numFr3" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 4</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir4" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr4" class="numFr" id="numFr4" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr4" class="numIr" id="numIr4" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>


    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
    <p style="float:right;position:absolute;margin-left:700px;margin-top:10px;" id="alertmessage"></p>
```

I had the following radio box and input text field. My purpose was do a validation to ensure user had do the selection for all the radio box and cannot be blank, I don't know how to validation on the radio box, so I do on the input text field that are empty. I had the following jquery but it only highlight the input text field, my expectation is **highlight entire row** and it will **jump to the row automatic** when it had not be answered when I click the button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the updated code below.

Added one class `invalid` in css.

Looped through the row of table and checked if any of the input is blank, if yes add `invalid` class to row else remove the class.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

```js
function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);

  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    validateNresult();
  })


  $('.allrb').change(valueE);


});


function validateNresult() {

  $.each($("tbody tr"), function(i, e) {
    var hasInvalidInputs = $(this).find(".numFr, .numIr").filter(function() {
      debugger
      return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    }).length > 0;

    if (hasInvalidInputs) {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }

  });

}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir3" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr3" class="numFr" id="numFr3" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 4</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr4" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir4" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir4 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr4" class="numFr" id="numFr4" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr4" class="numIr" id="numIr4" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 5</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr5" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir5" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir5 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr5" class="numFr" id="numFr5" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr5" class="numIr" id="numIr5" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showme" type="button">View Result</button>
<p style="float:right;position:absolute;margin-left:700px;margin-top:10px;" id="alertmessage"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sure this is what I want. =D

Comment: Welcome @Beginner! Glad it helped :-)